# A null pointer bug in linux

Tags: docker, linux-kernel

Recently, we met a kernel panic issue due to NULL pointer dereference in
the function ixgbevf_alloc_rx_buffers when up or down the VF into docker container. We
can reproduce the issue when up down vf in container.

Driver and kernel information:

driver: ixgbe
version: 4.4.0-k-rh7.3

driver: ixgbevf
version: 2.12.1-k-rh7.3

host kernel: centos 
Linux 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 4 15:04:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

BUG:

```
[15332.577915] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000008
    [15332.578277] IP: [<ffffffffa05dc610>] ixgbevf_alloc_rx_buffers+0x60/0x180 [ixgbevf]
    [15332.578569] PGD 3ed27a0067 PUD 3ed27a3067 PMD 0 
    [15332.579034] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 
    [15332.579512] Modules linked in: ixgbevf xt_set ip_set_hash_ipportnet ip_set_bitmap_port ip_set_hash_ipport ip_set_hash_ipportip ip_set dummy xt_comment xt_mark ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xt_conntrack br_netfilter bridge stp llc overlay(T) iptable_filter xt_addrtype iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 ip_vs_sh ip_vs_wrr ip_vs_rr ip_vs nf_conntrack intel_powerclamp coretemp intel_rapl iosf_mbi kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crc32_pclmul iTCO_wdt ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel iTCO_vendor_support mxm_wmi lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd mei_me ipmi_devintf pcspkr mei sg i2c_i801 lpc_ich ipmi_si ipmi_msghandler wmi shpchp acpi_power_meter ip_tables xfs libcrc32c sd_mod crc_t10dif crct10dif_generic crct10dif_pclmul ast crct10dif_common
    [15332.583611]  crc32c_intel drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt ixgbe fb_sys_fops ttm igb mdio ahci drm ptp libahci pps_core dca i2c_algo_bit libata megaraid_sas i2c_core fjes dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod
    [15332.586109] CPU: 30 PID: 302 Comm: kworker/u80:1 Tainted: G               ------------ T 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 #1
    [15332.587224] Hardware name: Sugon I610-G20/60G24-US, BIOS 006 08/07/2017
    [15332.588322] Workqueue: ixgbevf ixgbevf_service_task [ixgbevf]
    [15332.589099] task: ffff881ffd121f60 ti: ffff881ffd134000 task.ti: ffff881ffd134000
    [15332.589912] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffa05dc610>]  [<ffffffffa05dc610>] ixgbevf_alloc_rx_buffers+0x60/0x180 [ixgbevf]
    [15332.590770] RSP: 0018:ffff881ffd137d20  EFLAGS: 00010287
    [15332.591638] RAX: 0000000000000200 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000000
    [15332.592534] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00000000000001ff RDI: ffff883fe13eaf00
    [15332.593438] RBP: ffff881ffd137d58 R08: ffff881ffd134000 R09: 0000000000000000
    [15332.594361] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 0000000000000005 R12: 0000000000000000
    [15332.595300] R13: 00000000fffffe00 R14: 00000000000001ff R15: ffff883fe13eaf00
    [15332.596248] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff883fff280000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
    [15332.597224] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
    [15332.598231] CR2: 0000000000000008 CR3: 0000003ef3b68000 CR4: 00000000003407e0
    [15332.599257] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
    [15332.600281] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
    [15332.601325] Stack:
    [15332.602352]  ffff883f85ab3ba8 ffff881ffd137d38 ffff883f85ab38c0 0000000000000009
    [15332.603431]  ffff883f85ab3ba8 ffff883fe13eaf00 0000000000001028 ffff881ffd137db8
    [15332.604526]  ffffffffa05de7af 0000003e00000000 ffff883f85ab38c0 0000000000001028
    [15332.605641] Call Trace:
    [15332.606757]  [<ffffffffa05de7af>] ixgbevf_configure+0x5af/0x720 [ixgbevf]
    [15332.608078]  [<ffffffffa05e04b5>] ixgbevf_reinit_locked+0x65/0x90 [ixgbevf]
    [15332.609329]  [<ffffffffa05e172f>] ixgbevf_service_task+0x29f/0x370 [ixgbevf]
    [15332.610515]  [<ffffffff810a845b>] process_one_work+0x17b/0x470
    [15332.611710]  [<ffffffff810a9296>] worker_thread+0x126/0x410
    [15332.612916]  [<ffffffff810a9170>] ? rescuer_thread+0x460/0x460
    [15332.614136]  [<ffffffff810b0a4f>] kthread+0xcf/0xe0
    [15332.615371]  [<ffffffff810b0980>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x140/0x140
    [15332.616618]  [<ffffffff81697758>] ret_from_fork+0x58/0x90
    [15332.617877]  [<ffffffff810b0980>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x140/0x140
    [15332.619153] Code: c5 41 89 f6 49 89 c4 48 8d 14 40 48 8b 47 38 49 c1 e4 04 4c 03 67 18 48 8d 1c d0 0f b7 47 2c 41 29 c5 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 <48> 83 7b 08 00 74 76 8b 53 10 48 8b 03 48 01 d0 49 83 c4 10 48 
    [15332.621915] RIP  [<ffffffffa05dc610>] ixgbevf_alloc_rx_buffers+0x60/0x180 [ixgbevf]
    [15332.623301]  RSP <ffff881ffd137d20>
    [15332.624659] CR2: 0000000000000008
```

Does somebody have get this bug before?And how to fix it?

Comment: It's hard to understand the problem without more context. Can you be more specific about what you're doing when this happens and the environment you're using? (Other than the kennel, which I'm guessing is CentOS 7)

Comment: Is this even related to programming?

Comment: If you want *someone* to fix the problem for you, report it to the appropriate bug tracker. Stack Overflow is not a site for fix *other's* (not yours) code.

Comment: sorry， I use sriov in our environment.And i move a pf into a docker container.Then in the container i up and down this vf.Suddenly the host panic and the host should be reboot.

Answer (score 0):

we update lxbge resolve this problem:
pci:Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2
lxbge version: 5.3.7
kernel version: 4.4.138-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
linux release: Release: 7.4.1708